# firebase.auth().currentUser.uid - can't find uid of undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have a function as follows:

```
recieveUserData = async() =>{

console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);
let user =firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
await firebase.database().ref('/Users/'+user+'/Public').once('value').catch(error=>{console.log("error:" + error)}).then((snapshot)=>{


    //Do something.
})

        }
```

The console log, actually produces the uid. However,  the function that requires the variable 'user' and hence 'firebase.auth().currentUser.uid' fails:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of null].
```

I am thinking that perhaps firebase.auth() may take some time to be called and hence the later line errors out. I thought I could solve this by changing the above to something like the following:

```
console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);
       await firebase.auth()
       .catch(err=>{console.log(err)})
       .then(response=>{console.log(response)});
```

I was thinking I could write my later lines in the .then(), but I get a different error:

```
Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: _firebase.default.auth(...).catch is not a function]
```

I am very confused as I use something similar in a different module and it seems to work fine. I am slightly worried that it will break now given these errors. Any insight would be really handy.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please don't include the answer's code in your question. If you have a comment on an answer, leave that comment under *that* answer.

Comment: It's too big to put it in the comment lol.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use both sync and asynchronism at the same time.

You are not familiar with the use of '`async`' and '`await`'. If you understand '`sync`', you can see the problem with your code. You made it a '`async`' function and put '`await`' in the *firebase*. Then the function starts from **firebase**, so the value of '`user`' is not defined, and it generates null. This results in an error. `Promise` of '`.then`' is same the '`async`' and '`await`' function.

Could you try this code?

```js
//async
const {currentUser} = await firebase.auth()
let userUid = currentUser.uid

//sync
let userUid;
firebase.auth().then( currentUser => {
   userUid = currentUser.uid
})
.catch(error => console.log(error) )
```

Comment: I edited my code to the following based on your answer. The code SOMETIMES works. I am not sure why this is the case.

    recieveUserData = async() =>{
         
    
           const {currentUser} = await firebase.auth()
           let userUid = currentUser.uid;
    
           
    //console.log(userUid);
            
        await firebase.database().ref('/Users/'+userUid+'/Public').once('value').catch(error=>{console.log("error:" + error)}).then((snapshot)=>{//DO SOMETHING}));

Comment: After a play around, I think that my code is not implementing await correctly. it runs the next line without waiting and hence if it gets to the next line before Firebase has returned, I will get an error, but if Firebase is quicker the code works.Is it not possible to use await with firebase.auth() for some reason?

Comment: You are not familiar with the use of 'async' and 'await'. If you understand 'sync', you can see the problem with your code. You made it a 'async' function and put 'await' in the firebase. Then the function starts from firebase, so the value of 'user' is not defined, and it generates null. This results in an error. Promise` of '`.then`' is same the '`async`' and '`await`' function.

Comment: @HarryShotta If my answer was helpful, would you please select the 'V' sign and arrow for your answer?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry I am still not sure what you mean by this. What should I change my function to? recieveUserData = async() =>{ const {currentUser} = await firebase.auth() let userUid = currentUser.uid; //console.log(userUid); await firebase.database().ref('/Users/'+userUid+'/Public').once('value').catch(error=>{console.log("error:" + error)}).then((snapshot)=>{//DO SOMETHING}))

Comment: Sometimes it works fine (about 50% of the time). Sometimes I get the error: [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of null]. I have tried numerous different things now, including introducing promises and calling other independent functions and trying to .catch errors, but to no prevail :(. My latest  unsuccessful attempt: let promise = new Promise(  (resolve, reject)=>{resolve(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)});

        let result = await promise;

        alert (result); //still only sometimes works.

Comment: Even if I go back to absulte basics with     recieveUserData = async() =>{
       
        const {currentUser} = await firebase.auth();
        let userUid = currentUser.uid;
        console.log(userUid);
       }. I still get the same error.

Comment: Could you try remove await? `firebase.database().ref`

Comment: Again, I get the same result. Bizarrely, if it works the first time, it works every time after that. If I run the the following, it sometimes comes out as null at first, or sometimes comes out as the uid:  recieveUserData = () =>{ const {currentUser} = firebase.auth(); console.log(currentUser);} I've tried making it an async/await and a sync/.then function but I get the same result regardless.Is there something wrong with firebase.auth()? I have another module which is similar and uses the same principles and I have tested it many times but am not able to replicate the error.

Comment: submit = (closeFunction) =>{
let newWave ={
//declare object newWave - too many chars for comment.
if (this.state.format === "Voice")
{newWave.Content.Value = "N/A";
newWave.Content.Audio = '/Users/'+firebase.auth().currentUser.uid+'/Public/Waves';}   
this.setState({playing:true});
        firebase.database().ref('/Users/'+firebase.auth().currentUser.uid+'/Public/Waves').push({...newWave}).catch(err=>{console.log(err)}).then(async(snap)=>{
if (this.state.format === "Voice"){this.uploadImage(this.state.curRecording.getURI(),snap.key);}
closeFunction()});
        }

Comment: scratch that...the same thing has just happened with the other module as I feared it would. Must have just been lucky to not have come across the error the few times I tested it.

Comment: Before you get the data, you didn't log in properly, did?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I managed to test whether I was authenticated in ComponentDidMount in a parent module and render the relevent modules only if I was authenticated. I also used firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged as this would update as soon as I had been authenticated, i.e. it gave firebase enough time to return an actual currentUser and not null. This then meant my initial code/all other different solutions I have tried now actually work:

```
class WholeProject extends Component {


state={
    user:null
}

componentDidMount = () => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user)=>{
        if (user) {
            this.setState({ user });
        } else {
            this.setState({ user: null });
        }

    });}


render(){
let authenticated;
if (this.state.user === null)
authenticated=<Text>Unauthenticated</Text>;
else authenticated=<Profile user = {this.state.user}/>;


return(
<React.Fragment>
{authenticated}
</React.Fragment>

);

}
}

export default WholeProject;
```